# Сommand failed: unzip /home/alexander/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.zip

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I am trying to compile an application created on Kivy with the help of a buildozer, I encountered many errors, most of them decided, but I can’t deal with this error.

What should I do in this case?

This is what the buildozer in the terminal.

```
Archive:  /home/alexander/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk- 
r9c-linux-x86_64.zip
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is 
not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In 
the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be 
found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of 
/home/alexander/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c-linux- 
x86_64.zip or
/home/alexander/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c-linux- 
x86_64.zip.zip, and cannot find 
/home/alexander/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c-linux- 
x86_64.zip.ZIP, period.
# Command failed: unzip 
/home/alexander/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c-linux- 
x86_64.zip
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Looks like the Android API is not fully installed. Whatever this is doing appears to need the NDK, which is an optional part of the Android APIs, but you seem to need it. You could try installing the NDK and retrying, but you really ought to review the entire build system you are using to make sure this is expected and you have all the pieces necessary to actually build this code.

Comment: I assume that "buildozer" docs will walk you through this, assuming you are _intending_ to build an Android app (or whzat looks like `python_for_android`). If not, you should back up and check your config. If you are building an Android app, then you will need the appropriate version(s) of the API, and possibly also the NDK, and _then_ you need to tell anything that needs that where to find it. This is probably a bit too broad for SO, but you probably want to start here: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html

Comment: A lot of information. Let's figure it out:
1) Do i need to install android ndk?
2)I have read the documentation on the kivy website, but I don’t understand how it can help me.

Comment: I don't know because I don't know if you are pulling in a native component that will be linked into an Android app, or if python_for_android, kivy or buildozer needs it. Assuming you are using any of these. Surely step 1 is reading the relevant docs, no? They even explain when you might _need_ to manually download Android SDKs. All we know right now is that _something_ is failing because it cannot find the NDK. Whether it actually needs the NDK, or can't find it, or can't provide it automatically I think only you can answer right now.

Comment: Should I give the code a bulldozer?

Comment: For instance, you haven't shared how you have configured Kivy here. Are you using python-for-android? If so, do you understand the implications of that, and followed _those_ docs? There are a lot of moving parts here, and it is unclear what you need, and what you need to make that work.

Comment: My guess is that you are using buildozer and _not_ python-for-android, and buildozer has cached bad copies of one or more of the Android build tools as corrupted compressed files. I suspect there are options to that tool that reset the cache, but in a pinch you can just try and rename .builddozer to .buildozer_OLD and see what happens.

Comment: Well, tomorrow I will continue to study this problem and write to you.

Comment: Hi, Got any solution for this? I'm also facing the same issue. Pls let us know if you've solved it..

Answer (score 1):

I got this error earlier. It's very easy! The stock android-ndk-r9c almost never works. You must download the new r9c from the web and then unzip it in .buildozer/android/platform

But I advise you to download the version android-ndk-r13b from the web. r9c is a very old version and you can get some problems with new android APIs. r13b version works good.

You can download 7z, and unzip like:
cd .buildozer/android/platform
7z x the_name_of_your_ndk.zip

Good luck!

Comment: I've downloaded android-ndk-r20-linux-x86_64 and extracted  in the path as you mentioned,but still facing the same issue..any idea what could be the issue now?